# getting Image path while saving it in gallery and retrieve that Image later with path in iOS using swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using this code to save the image in gallery and its working fine, the image is saved in simulator's gallery.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var myImage : UIImage = UIImage(named: "sample")!
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myImage, self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)
    }

    func image(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo:UnsafePointer<Void>) {
        if error == nil {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Your altered image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
            presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
            presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

- How can I get the path of image which I just saved in gallery?
- Then using that path, how do I get the image back from gallery and use it in my application?

I am using Xcode 7.3 ans swift 2.0 Thanks in advance.

Comment: An easier option would be to store the image as a global variable.

Comment: I want to reuse the image when user open the application next time. So basically I can save its path in NSUserDefault, but how do I get the path ?

Comment: You can save the image directly using `NSKeyedArchiver`: `NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(myImage, toFile: "a/valid/file/path")`. Read the image back with `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile("the/file/path") as? UIImage`.

Comment: Thanks, but that is in Obj-c and I want it in swift

Comment: My comment is in Swift.

Comment: Thnaks can you please put it as answer with an example of valid path to the gallery so that I can accept it if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/) to select an image that has been saved to the gallery.  The delegate function `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` will supply you with a dictionary containing information about the image that was chosen.  The UIImage is contained in this dictionary under the `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` key.  You can read about the other keys available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Editing_Information_Keys).

Comment: Thanks But I do not want to use UIImagePIckerController, because I want this process to happen programatically. Basically something like saving a profile picture and getting it when the user open the app next time.

Comment: Ah.  Then when saving the image to the gallery you'll want to save it's filepath to another form of persistent storage, like a SQLite database or write it to NSUserDefaults like you mentioned in a comment earlier.  To get the path back after you've saved it to NSUserDefaults, you'll need to save the path under a key that stays constant so you know where to look for it in the defaults dictionary.

Comment: what I am asking is how do I get the path of image I just saved ? and lets say on a button click get image back using that path ? saving the path for later user is another story

Comment: How are you choosing the image initially?

Comment: The Image will be coming from a chat

Comment: If it's coming in as a UIImage with no prior path, instead of using `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` you could manually write it to a filename of your choosing.  There's an example of doing that as one of the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29009621/url-of-image-after-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum-in-swift).