# Cannot get URL for photo saved to PhotosAlbum in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm very green when it comes to Swift, and I'm just trying to get the file URL for a photo I've saved.  Below is a small [snippet inspired from this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29009621/url-of-image-after-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum-in-swift)

```
let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer)
// Save the photo to the album library
let image = UIImage(data: imageData)!
let orientation = ALAssetOrientation(rawValue: image.imageOrientation.rawValue)!
ALAssetsLibrary.writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum(image.CGImage, orientation: orientation, completionBlock: {
                                             (url: NSURL!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
    } else {
        // We have the URL here
    }
})
```

However, I can't for the life of me get it to build.  It's showing the following error:

> Cannot invoke 'writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum' with an argument list of
>   type '(CGImage?, orientation: ALAssetOrientation, completionBlock: (NSURL!,
>   NSError!) -> Void)'

And it's stating it expects:

> Expected an argument list of type '(CGImage!, orientation:
>   ALAssetOrientation, completionBlock:
>   ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock!)'

The one obvious issue I can see that's off is the CGImage parameter, but I have no clue how to change this, or if that's the only issue.  Has anyone seen this or see what my rookie mistake here is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an optional `image.CGImage`, the error says that you must unwrap it.

This should work.

```
let library = ALAssetsLibrary()
library.writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum(image.CGImage!, orientation: orientation, completionBlock: {
    url, error in
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
    } else {
        // We have the URL here
    }
})
```

The new Photos.framework does provide the functionality you're looking for. Here's the link to the [developer library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAssetCreationRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016395-CH1-SW1) containing relevant parts to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Right, but when I unwrap the optional, I don't get the additional !.  I'm still seeing the error:
`Cannot invoke 'writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum' with an argument list of type '(CGImage, orientation: ALAssetOrientation, completionBlock: (NSURL!, NSError!) -> Void)'`
And it still complains:
`Expected an argument list of type '(CGImage!, orientation: ALAssetOrientation, completionBlock: ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock!)'`

Comment: One thing I'd like to suggest is to switch to the new Photos Framework. Asset Library has been deprecated as of iOS 9. Here's the link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014408

Comment: This is just for a proof of concept and given I'm so close, I'd really like to see if I can just get this to work.  I'm not worried about this being in production.  Thank you very much for the link though.  If I can't get past this I'll definitely mark your answer as complete and proceed with the Photos Framework

Comment: You need to call this method on an instance of `ALAssetsLibrary`, and not on the class itself. Sorry I didn't catch that one immediatelly. @gordysc

Comment: You are my hero!  You have no idea how much this saved me!  Thank you!!

Comment: No problem! Just transition to the new framework when you have the chance, it'll save you a lot of trouble down the line.