# How to automatically attach last photo taken to Mail?

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm making an app that sends an email with the last photo taken (screenshot) attached, I'm stuck at adding the last photo taken.

I tried searching everywhere and only found the fetch code but didn't understand it and didn't know how to implement it in my code

```
func takeScreenshot(){

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image!, nil, nil, nil)

    }

    func sendMail(){
        let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail(){
            mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
            mail.setToRecipients(["test@test.com"])
            mail.setSubject("Test mail subject")
            mail.setMessageBody("Test mail body", isHTML: false)
        } else {
            self.mailFailedToSent()
        }

    }

    func mailFailedToSent(){
        let mailFailedToSentAllert = UIAlertView(title: "Could not send mail", message: "You need to add Mail account in Settings > Passwords & Accounts > Add Account", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        mailFailedToSentAllert.show()
    }

    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func reportButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {

        takeScreenshot()
        sendMail()
    }
```

EDIT: i tried what @user3344236 suggested and i got error at return image!:

```
 func getImage(asset: PHAsset) -> UIImage{
    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
    fetchOptions.fetchLimit = 1

    let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)

    if (fetchResult.firstObject != nil) {

        var lastAsset: PHAsset = fetchResult.lastObject as! PHAsset
        var image = UIImage()
        PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: lastAsset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100) , contentMode: .aspectFill, options: PHImageRequestOptions(), resultHandler: { (result, info) -> Void in

            image = result!

        })
        return image!  //Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'UIImage'
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a image in email body using MFMailComposeViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210571/how-to-add-a-image-in-email-body-using-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller)

Comment: This is about inserting an image in the body, not attachment and not how to automatically get the last photo and attach it

Comment: Use  Photos Framework , sort by creationDate ascending false, the feched array object [0] is what you need. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29009621/url-of-image-after-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum-in-swift

Comment: @user3344236 please check my EDIT im stuck