# How to get location of Image from PHPhotoLibrary?

Tags: xamarin.ios, uiimage, phphotolibrary

Since ALAssetLibrary Api is deprecated we are using PHPhotoLibrary to save images to PhotoAlbum

If we use ALAssetLibrary,we can able to get assetUri of the saved image, but we cannot able to get the same if we use PHPhotoLibrary .

**Example For assetUri-**

/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1ABD9386-B868-4B8D-9670-3F260D574569/data/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/

Is there another way to get the same path as mentioned above using PHPhotoLibrary?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

AssetUri  is not available with PHPhotoLibrary .

We can use `request.PlaceholderForCreatedAsset.LocalIdentifier` instead.

```
UIImagePickerController controller = new UIImagePickerController {
      SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum,
      ImagePickerControllerDelegate = new PickerDelegate(),
      MediaTypes = new string[] { UTType.Image }
};
this.PresentViewController(controller, true, null);


public class PickerDelegate: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
{
    public override void FinishedPickingImage(UIImagePickerController picker, UIImage image, NSDictionary editingInfo)
    {
        PHPhotoLibrary.SharedPhotoLibrary.PerformChanges(
            () => {
                PHAssetChangeRequest request = PHAssetChangeRequest.FromImage(image);
                string id = request.PlaceholderForCreatedAsset.LocalIdentifier;
            },
            (bool success, NSError error) => {
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Refer to

[How to get the URL of an image just added in PHPhotoLibrary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30196969/how-to-get-the-url-of-an-image-just-added-in-phphotolibrary)

[Get URL of a newly created asset, iOS 9 style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34774807/get-url-of-a-newly-created-asset-ios-9-style)