# How can I return a string of a photo filename?

Tags: ios

I am using either the camera or the library app to take/select an image

eg.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    // User has selected an image

    // To dismiss the image picker
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    // Select the Image of interest
    // retrieve the object via key from documentation
    self.imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

}
```

If I set a breakpoint at `self.imageView.image` and step down, I can get the image properties but I don't know how to get the filename.

Comment: maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784887/getting-image-name-of-iphone-photo-library) can help?

Comment: Code I'm finding is out of date unfortunately

Comment: what do you mean with is out of date????

Comment: @Dazzle have you tried the `AssetsLibrary` approach?

Comment: Sorry I am a noob, I know what I want to do but I am having trouble implementing code I am finding if someone could help that would be appreciated

Comment: @Dazzle It's not clear what you want to do. Why do you need the path, what do you want to do with it? Did you saved the image already? Do you want to save it? I'll be happy to help you with the code but need to understand the above.

Comment: Agree with @Dazzle - the code you have shown doesn't save the image anywhere, so there is no filename at this stage.  I think the answer you need is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887987/saving-a-photo-and-using-it-immidietly

Comment: I want the user to be able to select an image from their library and save the filename eg "JPG_001.jpg", and also to take a picture and save the filename but I think one will explain the other

Comment: @Dazzle the name of the image, that was saved to the camera roll, can't be modified. If you like to have control over the images file names you should save the images to your app folder.

Comment: I'm not looking to modify it, just save it / view it

Comment: @Dazzle you wrote that you want to change the filename.

Comment: The title says return the filename. The comments say I don't know how to get the filename. Any tips on how I can read the filename?