# Get file path of saved image to camera roll iOS (Obj-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, phphotolibrary

I used `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` to save image to Camera Roll, but I want to get a reference to get back to the same image. Is it possible? I have a [link](http://qiita.com/eggmobile/items/edc30a1c31db63eb297b) (albeit in Japanese) that says it's possible to get the file path, but as of what I understand this is during selection (using imagePicker) and not before/after taking a picture. What I want is to get the reference of the image, save it in CoreData, and the use it later to fetch the image.

Edit: It seems as if there is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457904/iphone-how-do-i-get-the-file-path-of-an-image-saved-with-uiimagewritetosavedpho/4458451#4458451) already but in the comments it says that ALAssetsLibrary is already deprecated and we should use PHPhotoLibrary instead.

Comment: Have you checked below answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Get All the Photos, Videos and Other Data With Using PHAsset Library. Here is Code to get All Videos in Array .

//For Video

```
allPhotosResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeVideo options:nil];
```

For Image you Can use this

//For Images

```
allPhotosResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:nil];
```

and You can Display it Using  **PHAsset** in UiTableview or Any Other Control.

Here is the URL of Demo ,

[AVPlayer Demo (Fetch Video With PHAsset Library)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fhdpaau0yxr25t8/VideoAppAJ.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

just pass the file name and extension to fetch the image

```
+(UIImage *)loadImage:(NSString *)fileName ofType:(NSString *)extension {
NSString * documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
UIImage * result = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.%@", documentsDirectoryPath, fileName, extension]];
return result; }
```